# how can i animate camera that follow a growing graph

Tags: animation, camera

I am trying to make comparison render and I am stack I don't know how to animate the camera follow the graph really smooth[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you looked into the Follow Path constraint?